# UIPopoverController crash on iPad running iOS 5.0.1?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am using a UIImagePickerController on iOS 5 with the iPad and my app just got rejected because it crashed on their end. It doesn't crash on my end but I am sure it has to do with the UIPopoverController.

Please just point anything out that looks bad!

To show the UIImagePickerController:

```
- (IBAction)photoLibraryiPad {
if (popoverController) {
    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [popoverController setDelegate:nil];
        [popoverController release];
    }
} else {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

        self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                  initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

        popoverController.delegate = self;

        [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:photolibrarybutton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

        [imagePicker release];
    }
}
```

}

**Then this is where it is crashing on their end:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    if ([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [popoverController setDelegate:nil];
    [popoverController release];
}

    [noimageAvailable setHidden:YES];
    UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:
                                     UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];  
    [imgPic setImage:originalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // Hide picker selector
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    [picker release];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1) When you release the popover, you should set the delegate to nil. `popoverController.delegate = nil` before calling `[popoverController release]`. Chances are if you try to use the picker multiple times, it will crash for you too.  The delegate is calling an object that no longer exists.

2) When checking to see if the popover is visible, check to make sure it exists first.

Comment: Also I believe I am leaking the popover controller in the else statement in the first code snippet, how should I properly release that?

Comment: I ended up fixing the crash. Turns out I had to dismiss the popover after the I dismiss the picker which makes sense. But anyway, how would I fix that leak anyway?

Comment: Looks good.  In the delegate method, set the delegate to nil for the picker before releasing it.